# How to get forever to print child process output to stdout.

Tags: node.js, logging, docker, forever

I'm running node app under forever in a docker container, how do I get all console.log output to show up on the console? I'm a beginner to docker so I assume the best way to log with docker is to simply log to stdout. If there's a better more proper way to do this I'm open to alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forever`, like standard `node`, simply logs to stdout as well so you shouldn't have to do anything special. Of course, if you start your container with `docker run -d` you'll have to run `docker logs -f myNodeContainer` to actually see the output live.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question because I also installed forever for the first time, ran it with just `forever server.js` and...nothing.

No node console messages, just the warnings about no --minUptime and no --spinSleepTime. I stopped the forever processes using `forever stopall` and went looking for the logs. Sure enough, in the forever log was all the stdout from my server.

I assumed I was missing an option to print to stdout, but apparently not. After reading this SO question, I launch a fresh terminal, run it again and it works - it now logs my server messages to the console.

Since then I have also experienced lots of strange issues with forever. Like it restarting the script continuously, even though the script fails to start within 1000ms (there was a syntax error in one of the files) - I stop it, run forever again (same options, same source files) and it does what it's supposed to (only runs the script once).

Not really an answer (sorry), but this is just in case anyone comes seeking information.